# Rendering 2D Mesh In C#

Tags: c#, xna, geometry, 2d, vertex

i'm using XNA with C# and i'm trying to create sort of a vertex based graphics system. so i have the following code so far

```
public class vertex {
    private Vector2 position;
    private Color color;

    public vertex(Vector2 position, Color color) {
        this.position = position;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public Vector2 Position {
        get { return position; }
        set { position = value; }
    }

    public Color Color {
        get { return color; }
        set { color = value; }
    }
}

public class mesh {
    private vertex[] vertecies;

    public mesh(int vertecies) {
        this.vertecies = new vertex[vertecies];
        for (int i = 0; i < vertecies; i++)
            this.vertecies[i] = new vertex(Vector2.Zero, Color.White);
    }

    public vertex[] Vertecies {
        get { return vertecies; }
        set { vertecies = value; }
    }
}
```

and then i have this function which renders a dot onto the screen

```
 private void RenderVertex(vertex v)
 {
     sb.Draw(world.blankTexture, v.Position, new Rectangle(1, 1, 2, 2), v.Color);
 }
```

now what i'm trying to create is a function called RenderMesh(mesh m) which renders a given mesh out of dots (vertecies) using the RenderVertex(vertex v) function. so basically i want to find every point between the vertecies of the mesh and fill it with dots. is there an algorithm for that? or should i take a completely different approach. because i'm trying to get i system that renders and handles dynamic shapes. so please help. thanks for reading :)

Comment: Why don't you try to read a rendering tutorial like this: http://www.riemers.net/? You basically want to reinvent wheel, or at least the software rendering.

Comment: What the heck?? You want to draw a bunch of pixel-sized polygons (sprite batch draws sprites as polygons), in the shape of a polygon. Why not just draw the polygon directly? Also: XNA already has [`VertexPositionColor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.vertexpositioncolor.aspx).

Comment: VertexPositionColor is for 3d polygons

Comment: You can use 3D poligons in 2D, games does the same.